# Set Class fields in jni

Tags: java, android, class, java-native-interface, field

Here is my scenario, I create a method in JNI that will be called in my java code. basically  the method is getting the list of a Certificate.

The method contains a certificate class parameter called CertInfo, it has fields (a byte array) called ckvalue and ckaid and I need to return the CertInfo class to the calling java method.

My question is how can I pass the value "12345678" to the field ckvalue that is inside the CertInfo?

```
jclass CertificateInfoClass = env->FindClass("CertInfo");

jbyte certval = env->GetFieldID( clazz, "ckvalue", "Ljava/lang/String;" );
```

Thanks in advance!:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is how can I pass the value "12345678" to the field
>   ckvalue that is inside the CertInfo?

Take a look at the functions/methods `SetStatic<Type>Field()`

Comment: thanks fredrik, ill give it a shot, btw another question, by any chance, do you know how to call a java class constructor inside a jni code>?

Comment: It is done automatically when you create the instance.

Comment: hmmmm, inside the constructor is setting the values of my public and final fields, i need to use the class as a parameter to the native method. is it possible to pass the class without properly instantiating the class?


ex. 
`code`

CertInfo[] certinfor_array;

getcertificatelistobj(certinfor_array);

`code`

Comment: You can access anything from JNI, the class is a clasd and an instance is an instance of the class.

Comment: thank you frederik, ill give you credit once i compile my work, my jni source code still not working, by chance, have you tried using cryptoki in your past project?